# Make p with img in it take full width of div

Tags: css

I have a paragraph with an image inside it, and I would like the paragraph to take the full width of the div so that the image will as well. Currently it displays like so:

[image]

I tried to apply the following:

```
.entry-content p { 
    text-align:justify;
}
```

But it didn't help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show BOTH HTML & CSS ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there's a couple of things that aren't correct in your assumptions.

First of all a `<p>` element is a block element by default and thus full-width (unless stated otherwise).

Secondly your image wont be full-width when the parent `<p>` tag will be.

So for the answer itself:
If your `.entry-content` element is the size you want it to be, add the following css rule:

```
.entry-content p img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

It could be possible you have to set the width to the `<p>` tag as well for the image to be able to handle percentages.

(haven't tested this code, but it should get you going).

Comment: Thank you! It did work when I set both the image and p to full width, I must have missed it when trying to change the widths